# CarbonCopy recipient issue

Tags: docusignapi

I believe there's an issue when sending out documents using REST API and 3rd party
accounts as senders where we try to get our account a cc back and it
doesn't appear in the management system while we get an email. This way the
envelope is not accessible when using our account and basically the only
option is to use the client account again to get the envelope status or
data. This does not reproduce when sending from that 3rd party account
using the DocuSign website. This way we get a correct CC that appears in
the 'completed' folder. It also works fine when sending form out DocuSign
account and setting the 3rd party account as a CC. This way this envelopes
successfully gets to their system. The difference that can be seen from the
API is that when a correct CC to our account is set, the userId is the same
as we can get from login_information request while in the case when we do
not get it into our system, the userId parameter is different but permanent across multiple envelopes sent while testing this way.

These test tell that it's not the case that CC person should be in the same
account with sender to get the envelope in his system. I've tested with 2
independent accounts and they still get CC and envelope access. I believe
that is a glitch or some kind of limitation and would appreciate any kind
of feedback on this.

(Also, is it allowed to send envelopes as other users under our integration if we
have their logins and passwords?)

Comment: Your problem description is not very clear here, what's a 3rd party account?  And I don't know what you mean by "client" account.  And who is the CC recipient, who gets the emails, and what type of routing order do you have setup?  Please clarify your question more...

Comment: Account 1: we have Integration key & credentials (our account)
Account 2: we have credentials only (3rd party or client means we do not own it actually)

We try to send envelope using Account 2 credentials and Account 1 integration key and add Account 1 as a CC on that envelope. Recipients are unrelated here but the CC has the last routing order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the system is behaving properly here.  In the DocuSign platform, the account that sends a signature request is the one that has complete access to it.  If you send a signature request from a given account and you include a CC recipient from a different account, then only the sending account will be able to see the CC in through the management system (i.e. the DocuSign Console).

The CC recipient from the other account will only receive the notification email and since they were not the sender they will not see it in their folders.

Comment: Why do I see the CCd envelopes in the Console if sent from site UI? If sent directly from our own account (Account 1) using REST and CCd to another account that envelope is also available from that account's Management Console.

Comment: Not sure what's going on with your accounts but I'm not able to reproduce this.  It's possible there's a bug that for some reason you are experiencing that I'm not but I can't think of why that would be at the moment.  Our system does do some interesting in that if you send a signature request or CC to a *new*, previously unseen username + email combination it creates what's called a "Signer Account" for that new user which is a limited account.  But when I CC an existing account through the API I see it show up in that account...

Comment: Turned out it does not reproduce on other accounts. Like if I use Account_2 integrator key and Account_1 credentials and CC Account_2 on that envelope, it does get to that account's 'completed' folder as a valid CC. Seems quite strange and account-based but still reproduced for our account on live environment which is a disaster to be honest. Could you also please edit your initial answer so it won't mislead anyone having CC issues of any kind?